# vlookup value to be checked - String vs Long (or Integer)

Tags: string, vba, vlookup

---

I am trying to read in a value through vlookup and convert it to another value via the lookup table and I must be able to read in both numbers and letters.

Below is my code...

```
Dim myVLookupResult As String
Dim myRange As Range
Dim value As String
Dim value1 As Long

value = "30"            ' works only if there is a character in the string
value1 = 30             ' because this is a long, it can't have characters

With Worksheets("vlookup")

    Set myRange = .Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(257, 9))

End With

myVLookupResult = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(value, myRange, 7, False)
MsgBox myVLookupResult
```

Now the part I can't figure out is the following and I really appreciate any help...

If I place the variable 'value' of type string into the command for .vlookup(**value**, myRange,7, False), I don't get an error as long as a character is in the string.  If **value** is all numbers, I get an error of 1004.

I need to be able to read / support both numbers and letters for the input argument that is used as the lookup value in the vlookup command.  Since I am designating value as type string, why would it fail if I enter 30 for example?  Obviously a string is not always a string in vba.

Again any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is contingent on what the Lookup range is.

If the the lookup range is text that looks like numbers then you need to use a string.

If the lookup range is numbers then you need to use a number. They need to match.

If the lookup range has both then you will need to do two vlookups and deal with the error.

```
Dim myVLookupResult As Variant
Dim myRange As Range
Dim value As String
Dim value1 As Long

value = "30"            ' works only if there is a character in the string
value1 = 30             ' because this is a long, it can't have characters

With Worksheets("vlookup")

    Set myRange = .Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(257, 9))

End With


myVLookupResult = Application.VLookup(value, myRange, 7, False)
If IsError(myVLookupResult) Then myVLookupResult = Application.VLookup(value1, myRange, 7, False)
If IsError(myVLookupResult) Then
    MsgBox "Value not found as a number or string"
Else
    MsgBox myVLookupResult
End IF
```

Comment: this is true even if all my data in the lookup table is set up as text only? (cell format to be of type text)

Comment: @ViggyTheBadMonkey in my experience, "format as text" is the single best way to wreck lookups.

Comment: @ViggyTheBadMonkey if your "numbers" are text that look like numbers then you will need to use a string in the first criterion of the vlookup.  the vlookup will not find `300` a match `{"200","300",400"}`.

Comment: I believe the following statement is true in that you can convert a number to a string but can't convert a string to a number.  Correct me if I'm wrong...

If that is true, then in order to convert any number to a string, I use the string_val = str(val) and that should convert the value stored in 'val' to a string and store in 'string_val'....correct?

Comment: You can convert a string to a number  `Dim Str as Str` | `Dim StrNum as Long` | `Str = "30"` | `StrNum = Clng(Str)`  This will error if the string is not a number but if the string is a number stored as a string it will change it to a long.  @ViggyTheBadMonkey but yes your second assumptions is true but I like `CStr()` instead.  But that is personal.

Comment: I got it to work as expected....thank you very much Scott Craner and everyone for your insight! My last comment was an error on my part because I did not specify a parameter to be an integer ..... when I did that, it works perfectly!