# VBA VLookup isn't finding a successful match

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am loading 2 csv input files into new workbook and then using the values in MDAAccountList to search for a record in AssetAllocExt using application.Vlookup. When the code runs and does the Vlookup part is returns Error 2042 and cannot find a match.  When I write the same Vlookup values as a normal formula it find a successful match and returns values.  I have used the same code previously without any issues so not sure if its a data format issue.  I have included data examples below.

**MDAAccountList**

```
AccountNumber
334324
364438
494757
496819
444165
444608
558425
450246
517853
```

**AssetAllocExt**

```
AccountNumber   Australian Equities Australian Equities %   Global Equities Global Equities %
334324  290980.26   0.3703  115411.3    0.1469

364438  121314.12   0.2496  50278.12    0.1034

494757  345521.5    0.294   226973.46   0.1931
```

```
Public Sub LoadMDAAccountList()

Dim WB As Workbook
Dim SourceWB As Workbook
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim ASheet As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

'Turns off screenupdating and events:
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual

'Sets the variables:
Set WB = ActiveWorkbook
Set ASheet = ActiveSheet
Set SourceWB = Workbooks.Open("C:\test\MDAAccountList.csv", local:=True)

'Copies each sheet of the SourceWB to the end of original wb:
For Each WS In SourceWB.Worksheets
    WS.Copy after:=WB.Sheets(WB.Sheets.Count)
Next WS

SourceWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
Set WS = Nothing
Set SourceWB = Nothing

WB.Activate
ASheet.Select
    Set ASheet = Nothing
    Set WB = Nothing

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub

'-------------

Public Sub LoadAssetAllocationExtract()

Dim WB As Workbook
Dim SourceWB As Workbook
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim ASheet As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

'Turns off screenupdating and events:
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual

'Sets the variables:
Set WB = ActiveWorkbook
Set ASheet = ActiveSheet
Set SourceWB = Workbooks.Open("C:\test\AssetAllocationExtract.csv", local:=True)

'Copies each sheet of the SourceWB to the end of original wb:
For Each WS In SourceWB.Worksheets
    WS.Copy after:=WB.Sheets(WB.Sheets.Count)
Next WS

SourceWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Set WS = Nothing
    Set SourceWB = Nothing

WB.Activate
ASheet.Select
    Set ASheet = Nothing
    Set WB = Nothing

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Sheets("AssetAllocationExtract").Activate
ActiveSheet.Name = "AssetAllocExt"

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub

'-------------

Public Sub CheckAssetAllocation()

Dim PortfolioAustEq As String
Dim PortfolioGlobEq As String
Dim PortfolioAustEqFound As Variant
Dim PortfolioGlobEqFound As Variant

Dim UniqueReference As String
Dim SelectedPortfolio As String

Dim Lookup_Range As Range

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual

Sheets("MDAAccountList").Activate
Range("A2").Activate
Range("A2").Select

Do
  SelectedPortfolio = ActiveCell.Value

  Set Lookup_Range = Range("AssetAllocExt!A:O")

  UniqueReferenceFound = Application.VLookup(SelectedPortfolio, Lookup_Range, 1, 0)
  PortfolioAustEqFound = Application.VLookup(SelectedPortfolio, Lookup_Range, 3, 0)
  PortfolioGlobEqFound = Application.VLookup(SelectedPortfolio, Lookup_Range, 5, 0)

Loop Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value)

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Make sure both numbers in MDAAccountList and AssetAllocExt got same format (numbers or text, but same on both).

Comment: `SelectedPortfolio` is declared as a string - so I guess it's looking for the `AccountNumber` as a string..Perhaps they're not?

Comment: Hi.  Both files are csv format so no formats in the files.  The only formatting that would be applied would be during the Copy process.  The formats appear the same as a normal VLookup formula works fine.

Comment: @CLR is correct, you are allocating your not formatted value to a string, and try to match against an INT/LONG... hence the error. Either change the variable `SelectedPortfolio` to a LONG (or other correct datatype), or you can do that in your vlookup (`cLong(SelectedPortfolio)`). I`ll post a corrected version below.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  All working now.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a more detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45762198/vlookup-value-to-be-checked-string-vs-long-or-integer) about the issue you are having, but long stort short, making the change @CLR suggested is what you need.

Meanwhile, see below the

```
...
Dim SelectedPortfolio As Long 'or change the correct datatype
...
```

In essence, what you are trying to do in the code is something like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(TEXT(SelectedPortfolio, "0"), Lookup_Range, 1, 0)
```

Which will not work in the spreadsheet either.